# Crontab running bash script logs "command not found"

Tags: 18.04, cron

I'm trying to run a command at certain intervals.

`pm2 restart appname`

Doing this myself works. Then I add it to a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
pm2 restart appname
```

Running the bash script works: `bash scriptname.sh`

Then I add it to my crontab:

`* * * * * /usr/local/crontab-scripts/scriptname.sh >> /var/log/cronlog.log 2>&1`

This gives me the error:`/usr/local/crontab-scripts/scriptname.sh: line 4: pm2: command not found`

I'm not doing any of this as root, I have pm2 globally installed, I put into my script `whereis pm2` and it logged the correct path `/usr/local/bin/pm2`. Then I tried having my script cd to that path before running pm2, no difference.

I'm out of ideas here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call applications or commands from within scripts or CRON jobs, it helps to spell out the entire path of the application.

In your case I would try re-writing your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/pm2 restart appname
```

However, this seems like overkill and you might as well just call `pm2` directly from your crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/pm2 restart appname >> /var/log/cronlog.log 2>&1
```